# Unable to swap old server with new one as the switch it's plugged into is unaccessible

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, cisco-catalyst

Hopefully the title covers this question but, it's pretty straightforward.

At work, we have an old DMZ Server we'd like to replace with a newer model. Unfortunately, when we were ready for the swap, the NIC didn't light up (*no link lights*). So we plugged in the old DMZ Server and link lights to that server were re-established.

- we now know it's most likely on sticky Mac.

We attempted to contact the sticker that points to a local network help desk for assistance but, they claim they dont manage it and have given us the run-around since then. Just been back and forth of "we don't manage it, not out switch".

Fine, we decided to try and spoof the MAC through the registry, with no luck. It shows that it has changed, but the only thing that hasn't is the virtual nic.

Has anyone ever had to deal with a mess like this?

- Attempted to spoof MAC; no luck. *We were advised to do so*.
- Attempted to access the switch since we have direct access (*physically*) to it.

Can anyone suggest what options we have in this scenario? What would you all do?

*The switch is a Cisco Switch 3650*

Pardon the hefty paragraph, but thank you for taking the time to read it.

Comment: [reset the admin password on the switch](https://community.cisco.com/t5/other-network-architecture/urgent-password-recovery-with-the-3650/td-p/2629200)

Comment: @Gerald, we saw that as well on our Google search dive. Just afraid of it wiping out the configs. Our NetOps teams isn't any help either.

Comment: `spoof the MAC through the registry, with no luck. It shows that it has changed, but the only thing that hasn't is the virtual nic.` Not a lot of detail there. Most people use Set-NetAdapter.

Comment: @Greg, wasn't aware that was a cmdlet. I'll give it a go come Monday. Tried changing the CIM instance property as well but, it didn't change lol

Comment: At some point you will have to do it. You might just as well so it now.

Comment: Regarding length of your question, that is actually the proper length to include necessary details. Problem description, make and model of affected hosts, level of access you have, and what you attempted. Could use a an edit with bit more about MAC spoofing on the Windows box, per Greg's comment.